# Can't understand these errors coming from image upload form

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having this errors:

imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs file_put_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 80000))
  {
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
    {
        echo "Error:".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."</br>";
    }
else
    {
        echo "Upload: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."</br>";
         echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
          echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
          echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
          $tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

     if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
        $image = file_get_contents($tmp);
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        file_put_contents($image, $new_image);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
  }
  }
  else
  {
      echo"Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$image = file_get_contents($tmp);
```

To:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmp));
```

`imagecopyresampled` expects the second parameter to be a GD image resource, not a string which is the result of `file_get_contents`. Use `imagecreatefromstring` to convert that string representation of an image to an image resource.

Comment: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs....now i am getting this error

Comment: Wouldn't `imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp)` (or similar) be much easier (and more

Comment: @tdammers, `imagecreatefromstring` makes the loading file-type-independent, you can load .PNG, .GIF, .JPG files etc. with one expression. @Birju, use `imagejpeg()` to save the image, also read some tutorial about image manipulation in PHP.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: It also requires loading the entire file into a PHP string and then passing that string back into GD. It's not much overhead, but just giving GD a filename and letting it do its thing is probably more efficient, provided you know the file type beforehand.